# Power series expansion of $\log z$

Tags: complex-analysis

In a book I'm reading it says: since
\begin{equation} \frac{1}{z} = \frac{1}{1-(1-z)}\end{equation}
The power series expansion of $\frac{1}{z}$ about $z_0=1$ is:
\begin{equation} \frac{1}{z} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (1-z)^n= \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n (z-1)^n\end{equation}

Now what I don't get is the logic behind such reasoning. It might be basic but I just don't see how you can get a series expansion simple as that. Can someone help me please?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's using

$$ \frac{1}{1-w} = \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} w^n $$

for $|w| < 1$.